# CMake error in macro with target_link_libraries

Tags: hyperlink, macros, cmake

I wrote a macro that calls the function TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES:

```
macro(Link_Libs cur_target)

#ATLAS LIBS on Linux

add_library(ptlapack STATIC IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET ptlapack PROPERTY
                IMPORTED_LOCATION /usr/local/atlas/lib/libptlapack.a)

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(cur_target ptlapack)
endmacro()
```

Then I called the macro from project

```
project(CPU_Matrix)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

aux_source_directory(./src/ SRC_LIST1)
include_directories(./include/)  

add_executable(CPU_Matrix ${SRC_LIST1} )

INCLUDE(${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH}/LinkLibs.txt NO_POLICY_SCOPE)
Link_Libs(CPU_Matrix_Class_Test_Satisfy)
```

When I run CMake, it gave error:

```
Cannot specify link libraries for target "cur_target" which 
is not built by this project
```

How can I link libraries in a macro?

Answer (score 3):

It's probably just because you're not dereferencing the variable `cur_target` inside the macro.  You'd have to do:

```
target_link_libraries(${cur_target} ptlapack)
```

As well as this, you'd only be able to call this macro once since you can't keep re-adding ptlapack over and over.  You should add a guard to avoid trying to add the library multiple times, e.g.

```
if(NOT TARGET ptlapack)
  add_library(ptlapack STATIC IMPORTED)
  set_property(TARGET ptlapack PROPERTY
               IMPORTED_LOCATION /usr/local/atlas/lib/libptlapack.a)
endif()
```

Finally, it's not good practice to specify a local path like this.  "/usr/local/atlas/lib/libptlapack.a" may be where the library is on your machine, but that may not be the case for every machine, and it's certainly not cross-platform :-)

Comment: Thank you it works. I learn library. How to link libraries that are installed by myself (not from repository)?

Comment: You can use [`find_library`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/command/find_library.html) to locate the library.